# How to set permission to twig template

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I have created a twig template using which I am displaying the some content on the front end. I want this template to be accessible only for a particular role. could anyone please tell me how can I set the permission.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in controller where you render this view.
However you could wrap template in condition

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    {# template content #}
{% endif %}
```